# Using Perl and LibXML to obtain sub node values when namespace is used

Tags: perl, libxml2

I have the following XML as an example:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema" >
    <parentNode status="Good">
        <A>
            <B>
                <C id="123" >C Node Value Here</C>
            </B>
        </A>
    </parentNode>
</root>
```

There are multiple parentNode nodes in my XML file (only one shown here), so I am cycling through parentNode's.  Once I have one, I want to obtain attribute values 3 more levels down in the XML.  My XML uses a name space and I have registed the name space in my Perl script as "plm".  I can obtain the parentNode attribute value just fine using name space in my path.  But when I try to navigate down to node "C" and pickup attribute "id", I am getting the following error:

XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
 error : xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed

I am using the following Perl script.

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $filename = "namespaceissue.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($filename);
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $doc->documentElement()  );
$xc->registerNs('plm', 'http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema'); 

foreach my $node ($xc->findnodes('/plm:root/plm:parentNode')) {
    my $status  = $node->findvalue('./@status');
    print "Status = $status\n";

    my $val = $node->findvalue('./plm:A/plm:B/plm:C/@title');
    print "Value = $val\n";

}
```

If I use no namespace on the sub-nodes ./A/B/C, the script continues with no error, but no value is assigned to $val.  If I add the plm: prefix I get the namespace error.  Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? Do I have to use findnodes to first find the subnodes and then extract the value with findvalue?  I tried that as well and did not have any luck.

Answer (score 4):

```
$node->findvalue('./plm:A/plm:B/plm:C/@title')
```

should be

```
$xc->findvalue('./plm:A/plm:B/plm:C/@id', $node)
```

---

Tips:

- Those leading `./` are useless.

  ```
  $node->findvalue('./@status')

  $xc->findvalue('./plm:A/plm:B/plm:C/@id', $node)
  ```

  are the same as

  ```
  $node->findvalue('@status')

  $xc->findvalue('plm:A/plm:B/plm:C/@id', $node)
  ```
- You can use `getAttribute` to get an element's attribute, so

  ```
  $node->findvalue('@status')
  ```

  can also be accomplished more efficiently using

  ```
  $node->getAttribute('status')
  ```

Comment: Thank You.  I actually had a typo in what I published, so the following actually fixed my issue.  I will have to read up some more on findvalue now. my $val = $xc->findvalue('./plm:A/plm:B/plm:C/@id', $node);